# I am trying to translate a motto to latin that says, "a star of hope shines light in darkness"

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

I am trying to bridge together the concept of hope, being something that brings light to darkness using a star as a metaphor for hope. I haven't had much luck with online translators and am hoping for some recommendations. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

- If we have some liberty we can say:

**Stella/Sidus lumine spei tenebras lustrat** (Literally: Star illuminates the darkness with light of hope). In fact, we can have *Stalla spei lumine* and let the reader decide to what *spei* (of hope) relates to.

Or, instead of *stella* we can have *stella spei* (=star of hope) and use *lumine* alone.

There are [quite many attestations](https://latin.packhum.org/concordance?q=lumine%20%7E%20lust) for *lustrare lumine* (to illuminate/shine with light).

- If we want "shines" alone (as opposed to "illuminates"/"makes bright". i.e., without the object but with the location), we can use the verb *lueco* or *effulgeo* and say:

**Stella spei [etiam] (in) tenebris lucet**, or better perhaps, we can replace *Stella* with *lumen* (c.f. **in tenebris lumen effulsit** (Seneca *Moral letters* 120))

Comment: This is helpful thank you!